# Python: Recursive function with keyword arguments with default values

Tags: python, recursion, keyword-argument

I have a recursive function in my python script which looks something like this:

```
def recurse(nodes, keep_x=False, keep_y=False):
   for node in nodes:
      if not keep_x:
         node.pop('x', None)
      if not keep_y:
         node.pop('y', None)

      # Node may contain keys with lists of other nodes, so apply the function recursively
      for key in node.keys():
         if isinstance(node[key], list):
            node[key] = recurse(node[key], keep_x=keep_x, keep_y=keep_y)
```

This works but it doesn't seem very elegant to me to re-specify the keyword arguments in the recursive call.

Now if I would not have the default values I could do it like this:

```
def recurse(nodes, **kwargs):
   for node in nodes:
      if not kwargs['keep_x']:
         node.pop('x', None)
      if not kwargs['keep_y']:
         node.pop('y', None)

      # Node may contain keys with lists of other nodes, so apply the function recursively
      for key in node.keys():
         if isinstance(node[key], list):
            node[key] = recurse(node[key], **kwargs)
```

But this has the trouble that I have to add additional checks which keyword args actually got passed in or risk key errors.

What if I want to keep the default values for the keyword arguments? Is there a way to access the list of passed in keyword arguments (with default or overridden value) for the recursive call? Something like this (does not work in practice):
`recurse(node[key], **self.kwargs)`

Comment: Instead of `if not kwargs['delete_x']` (which will give you a keyerror if the value isn't present), have you tried changing the check to `'delete_x' in kwargs` (which will not)?

Comment: `delete_x` is an odd name for a parameter that removes `x` when it is *false*.

Comment: Should the second loop be inside the first loop?

Comment: Consider defining a recursive helper function inside `recurse` that closes over `delete_x` and `delete_y`.

Comment: @chepner you are right about `delete_x`, the variable/keyword arguments is named differently in the my actual code. Also right about the second loop, should be inside of the first.
Updated the question to fix both of these.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Haven't thought about that but sounds like a pretty elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

One simple change is to define an inner recursive function that can see `delete_x` and `delete_y` as non-local variables, avoiding the need to pass them to each recursive call.

```
def recurse(nodes, keep_x=False, keep_y=False):

    def helper(nodes):
       for node in nodes:
          if not keep_x:
             node.pop('x', None)
          if not keep_y:
             node.pop('y', None)
    
          for key in node.keys():
             if isinstance(node[key], list):
                node[key] = helper(node[key])

    return helper(nodes)
```

(Ignoring the issue of what `helper` should actually return, as the original `recurse` doesn't how a return value either.)